# JNA throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError for a Windows API function in the correct DLL with the correct name

Tags: java, windows, jna

JNA is throwing:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'DsMakeSpn': The specified procedure could not be found
```

for a mapping where I've verified that [`DsMakeSpn` exists in `ntdsapi.dll` according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676007(v=vs.85).aspx) and I'm on Windows Server 2008, so the function is available. JNA loads `ntdsapi.dll` without error.

I've extended `StdCallLibrary` since it's a `WINAPI` function; it isn't a linkage issue.

This makes very little sense.

The code with javadoc trimmed for brevity:

```
import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

interface NTDSAPI extends StdCallLibrary {

    NTDSAPI instance = (NTDSAPI)
            Native.loadLibrary("NTDSAPI", NTDSAPI.class);

    int DsMakeSpn(
            String serviceClass, /* in */
            String serviceName, /* in */
            String instanceName, /* in, optional, may be null */
            short instancePort, /* in */
            String referrer, /* in, optional, may be null */
            IntByReference spnLength, /* in: length of buffer spn; out: chars written */
            byte[] spn /* out string */
            )
        throws LastErrorException;

    public final int 
        ERROR_SUCCESS = 0,
        ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
        ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW = 111;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ntdsapi.dll` actually exposes two variants of `DsMakeSpn`, as shown by [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/):

[image: screenshot from dependency walker]

There's an ANSI and a Wide (unicode) variant.

MSVC will resolve these automatically. JNA won't. So you need to explicitly declare your mapping, declaring `DsMakeSpnW` and using `WString`s. e.g.:

```
    int DsMakeSpnW(
            WString serviceClass, /* in */
            WString serviceName, /* in */
            WString instanceName, /* in, optional, may be null */
            short instancePort, /* in */
            WString referrer, /* in, optional, may be null */
            IntByReference spnLength, /* in: length of buffer spn; out: chars written */
            char[] spn /* out string */
            )
        throws LastErrorException;
```

Note the change of buffer from `byte[]` to `char[]` for unicode calls.

See https://github.com/twall/jna/issues/377 for issue report.

If you want to expose both variants you can use the [`W32APIFunctionMapper`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIFunctionMapper.html).

Comment: See [W32APIOptions](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.java), which handles both the suffix mapping and the type mapping for you.  Using these options allows you to omit the "-A" or "-W" suffixes and use `String` in place of `WString`.

Comment: @technomage Thanks for the tip; will test if I get time.